# After reload page input values not reset

Tags: firefox, input

I have problem with Firefox browser after reload page input values not reset, witch Chrome browser values reset.

Comment: Did you reset them in code? If not, why not just do that. document.forms[0].reset().

Comment: I using wordpress plugin, I don't know do this is possible